# Can nservicebus support multiple transport mechanisms?

Tags: nservicebus

I have an on Premise Host that is using an AzureQueue configuration that pulls from an azure queue. I also have another on premise Host that is using MSMQ for its transport. I need to send a message from the first host to the second host (again both are on premise, but one is configured to use azure queue for transport).

What is the best way to accomplish this? Is the gateway a solution for this or am i missing something obvious?

Comment: Would it be possible to convert one of the endpoints to match the transport of the other?  Another option would be to expose one of the endpoints using the built-in WCF integration.

Comment: Interesting question: This is not available out of the box... but in theory what you have to do is make sure that the IMessageSender implementation in the container is the msmq one and the IMessageReceiver is the azurequeue one. But than it is for all messages the same, send goes through msmq, receive from azure. You'll have to manually wire everything together though (and never tried it myself either)

Comment: Or you could start a second transport and forward from one to the other. Setting this up is pretty similar to how the timeout manager works when hosted next to your handlers. See https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/blob/master/src/timeout/NServiceBus.Timeout.Core/TimeoutRunner.cs for some ideas

Comment: I think this will be achievable with long awaited multi-host option, in the NSB user group the discussion lasts since May and now it is still in progress, we\ll see what comes out.